# Python "gzip" module acting weirdly if compressed extension is not ".gz"

Tags: python, compression, gzip

I need to compress a file using the [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) module, but the output file extension may not be `.gz`.

Look at this simple code:

```
import gzip
import shutil

input_path = "test.txt"
output_path = input_path + ".gz"

with open(input_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write("abc" * 10)

with gzip.open(output_path, 'wb') as f_out:
    with open(input_path, 'rb') as f_in:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

It works fine. But if I replace `".gz"` with `".gzip"` for example, then I am not able to open the compressed file correctly:

[image: Uncompressing not working]

I tried with 7-Zip and WinRar, the result is the same, and the bug persists even if I rename the file.

Does anyone know where the problem comes from, please?

I tried with compression [`bz2`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bz2.html) and [`lzma`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html), they seem to work properly no matter what the extension is.

Comment: Do the files differ?

Comment: @StefanPochmann It looks like as theire size differ.

Comment: Why are you trying this, btw? `.gzip` seems to be nonstandard. At least the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) only mentions the `.gz` extension. If you tried output name `test.txt.foo`, would you expect it to recognize that as gzipped as well?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Because I need to compress arbitrary `.tar` file given in input to `.tgz`. I think I will end up with compressing to `.tar.gz` to ensure the `gzip` command works well, and then rename to `.tgz` but this is weird anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have two versions of file created this way:

First, `.gz` file:

```
with gzip.open("test.txt.gz", 'wb') as f_out:
    with open("test.txt", 'rb') as f_in:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Second, `.gzip` file:

```
with gzip.open("test.txt.gzip", 'wb') as f_out:
    with open("test.txt", 'rb') as f_in:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

Both create a GZIP with your `test.txt` in it. The only difference is that in the second case, `test.txt` is renamed to `test.txt.gzip`.

---

The problem is that the argument to `gzip.open` actually has two purposes: the filename of the gzip archive **and** the filename of the file inside (bad design, imho).

So, if you do `gzip.open("abcd", 'wb')` and write to it, it will create gzip archive named `abcd` with a file named `abcd` inside.

But then, there comes magic: if the filename endswith `.gz`, then it behaves differently, e.g. `gzip.open("bla.gz", 'wb')` creates a gzip archive named `bla.gz` with a file named `bla` inside.

So, with `.gz` you activated the (undocumented, as far as I can see!) magic, whereas with `.gzip` you did not.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I was currently investigating. Actually, I can read correctly the compressed content if I do `gzip.open(output_path)`, but I cannot if I use 7-Zip or WinRar. I looked at the source code on Github, and I found [the behavior you are describing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a4d00012565d716db6e6abe1b8f33eaaa4de416e/Lib/gzip.py#L230-L231). If I manually edit the module source code on my computer, and add `else: fname = b''` it seems to fix it. So I guess I will open an issue on the Python bug tracker and propose a patch to see what Python core developers think of it.

Comment: @Delgan You can use 7 zip to extract the file from the archive and then open it in notepad. It is still usable, just the filename is messed up. Anyway, yes, I think you should propose a change in Python. The behaviour depending on extension is not python-like.

Comment: I opened [an issue on the bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue32698) but I closed it shortward after that because there is a workaround using [`gzip.GzipFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile).

Answer (score 3):

The filename inside the archive can be controlled by utilising `gzip.GzipFile` constructor instead of the `gzip.open` method. The `gzip.GzipFile` needs then a separate `os.open` call before it.

```
with open(output_path, 'wb') as f_out_gz:
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f_out_gz, filename=input_path, mode='wb') as f_out: 
        ...
        f_out.flush()
```

Note also the added `f_out.flush()` - according to my experience without this line the `GzipFile` may in some cases randomly not flush the data before the file is closed, resulting in corrupt archive.

Or as a complete example:

```
import gzip
import shutil

input_path = "test.txt"
output_path = input_path + ".gz"

with open(input_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write("abc" * 10)

with open(output_path, 'wb') as f_out_gz:
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f_out_gz, filename=input_path, mode='wb') as f_out
        with open(input_path, 'rb') as f_in:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
            f_out.flush()
```